# Stat change discrepancy?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, hovering over a new item for a slot and pressing shift will show you an item comparison. I have recently got some new gloves which have got +320 spirit on them, however when I perform an item comparison it says that I will gain +532 spirit. I do no think this is correct.

[image: Item stat comparison]

I have taken a screenshot demonstrating my query, I'm not quite sure where these numbers have come from in this instance, am I missing something obvious or does this look broken to anybody else?

Comment: Using any mods?

Comment: I have a variety of addons, but experience the same discrepancies with them disabled, I've also only noticed this behavior with this particular item, and equipping it does not provide the bonus stated on the item (taking into consideration the gem and the reforge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison tooltips only know base stats and do not consider reforging changes.

The [Guardian Serpent Gloves](http://www.wowhead.com/item=85364/guardian-serpent-gloves) do have +532 spirit, prior to being reforged (Spirit -> Crit).

Enchants, gems, socket bonuses and set bonuses are also not considered by the comparison tooltips.

Comment: I'm aware it ignores any user modifications to the items (enchants, gemming, reforging), but if you look at the screenshot the spirit on the new gloves is reported as +320, rather than +532, even without any addons enabled. How peculiar...

Comment: @pixel It looks like the Guardian Serpent Gloves have already been reforged.

Comment: OH WOW /facepalm - I totally didn't notice that

Comment: That +320 spirit is the result of reforging. The gloves were reforged Spirit -> Crit. The gloves start with 0 crit and the tooltip comparison reflects that as well.  Editted to make it more clear.

Comment: I think this is why grinding video games is bad for your health in the long run, I feel somewhat silly now... cheers guys